# get values of previous rows as list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to get the values of the previous three rows in a new column?

```
data = { 'foo':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = some_function(x)

print(df)

  foo  bar
1  a   None
2  b   None
3  c   None
4  d   ['a','b','c']
5  e   ['b','c','d'] 
6  f   ['c','d','e']
7  g   ['d','e','f']
```

I could use the following method, by adding columns and then merging it to a new one, but i wonder if there is a better way to do this

```
def some_function_v1(df)
    df[foo1] = df.foo.shift(1)
    df[foo2] = df.foo.shift(2)
    df[foo3] = df.foo.shift(3)
    df['bar'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['foo1'],x['foo2'],x['foo3']], axis=1)
    df = df.drop(columns=[foo1,foo2,foo3]
    return df
```

Comment: looks like `some_function` has to change? please post the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view) on `foo` to create a new DataFrame with the grouped lists:

```
window = 3
bar_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bar': np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(df['foo'], window).tolist()
})
```

Offset the index:

```
bar_df.index += window
```

`bar_df`:

```
         bar
3  [a, b, c]
4  [b, c, d]
5  [c, d, e]
6  [d, e, f]
7  [e, f, g]
```

Then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the original frame:

```
out = df.join(bar_df)
```

`out`:

```
  foo        bar
0   a        NaN
1   b        NaN
2   c        NaN
3   d  [a, b, c]
4   e  [b, c, d]
5   f  [c, d, e]
6   g  [d, e, f]
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

window = 3
bar_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bar': np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(df['foo'], window).tolist()
})
bar_df.index += window

out = df.join(bar_df)

print(out)
```

Comment: upvoted for the great answer but had to upvote: it was 9990!

Comment: @HenryEcker Congrats on 10K +1!

Comment: thank you, this solution is much more efficient than creating helper columns. especially when the df is quite big.

Answer (score 2):

We can try *list comprehension* to generate sliding window view

```
n, v = 3, df['foo'].to_numpy()
df['bar'] = [None] * n + [v[i: i + n] for i in range(len(v) - n)]
```

Alternative approach with `sliding_window_view` method

```
n, v = 3, df['foo'].to_numpy()
df['bar'] = [None] * n + list(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(v[:-1], n))
```

---

```
  foo        bar
0   a       None
1   b       None
2   c       None
3   d  [a, b, c]
4   e  [b, c, d]
5   f  [c, d, e]
6   g  [d, e, f]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with `zip` to shift and merge lists element-wise instead of creating new columns-

```
df['bar'] = pd.Series(zip(df.foo.shift(3), df.foo.shift(2), df.foo.shift(1))).apply(lambda x:None if np.nan in x else list(x))
```

Here's a function to make the shift dynamic-

```
n_shift = lambda s, n: pd.Series(zip(*[s.shift(x) for x in range(n,0,-1)])).apply(lambda x:None if np.nan in x else list(x))

df['bar'] = n_shift(df.foo, 3))
```

Output-

```
  foo  bar
1  a   None
2  b   None
3  c   None
4  d   ['a','b','c']
5  e   ['b','c','d'] 
6  f   ['c','d','e']
7  g   ['d','e','f']
```

Comment: a possible solution but less dynamic if i want to extend the window, anyhow thanks for your thougths

Comment: Added a dynamic function as well.